# gcc: Enable AVX on AMD

Tags: c++, gcc, cmake, clion, avx

I have been trying to get AVX to run properly yet I am not able to compile my c++ project.
I am new to C++ and the compiling so I use CMake together with CLion and GCC.

[image]

I know that my processor supports AVX and AVX2 and I wrote a simple test program:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
...

    __m256 A{};
    __m256 B{};
    __m256 AB = _mm256_add_ps(A,B);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        std::cout << AB[i] << std::endl;
    }
```

Sadly when trying to run this, I get the following error:

```
warning: AVX vector return without AVX enabled changes the ABI [-Wpsabi]
   91 |     __m256 AB = _mm256_add_ps(A,B);
      |                                  ^
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/include/immintrin.h:51,
                 from A:\OneDrive\ProgrammSpeicher\CLionProjects\Koivisto\src_files\main.cpp:85:
C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.1.0/include/avxintrin.h:147:1: error: inlining failed in call to 'always_inline' '__m256 _mm256_add_ps(__m256, __m256)': target specific option mismatch
  147 | _mm256_add_ps (__m256 __A, __m256 __B)
```

I assume I need to set some flag in my CmakeLists.txt but I didnt find anything for this on the web.

I am very happy if someone could help me out!

Greetings,
Finn

## SOLUTION

I had to add

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -march=native")
```

and it will compile nicely.

Comment: You need `-march=native` (or just `-mavx`, but that's worse).

Comment: How do i enable that using cmake?

Comment: Ah i got it! Thank you